# `pip install --upgrade ` behaves differently for pyproject.toml and requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

If I have a `venv` with `black==22.12.0` installed and I run `pip install --U black` then `pip` will update to the newest version of black. I will see same behavior if `black` is listed in a requirements.txt and I run `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`. In this case pip eagerly updates if a new version is available.

Now suppose I have a `venv` with and editable install created with `pip install -e .` from a `pyproject.toml` (example below). If this has `black==22.12.0` installed and if I then run `pip install -U -e .` then black is not updated to the latest version. If I pin in the version of black in `pyproject.toml` to say `black>=23" then` pip install -U -e .` will update black. In this case pip only updates if the current version does not satisfy the requirements.

I cannot find anything in the docs describing this behavior. Is it intentional or a fault that `pip install -U` behaves differently in these two contexts?

Tests are made pip version 23.0.1 and python 3.10.10

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=65.5"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "packaging_example"
version = "0.0.7"

description = "python packaging example"
requires-python = "==3.10"

dependencies = [
  "black"
]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```